# How to show data in detail product?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, store, bulma

I have a products array inside Products.vue, ProductHome.vue, and ProductDetail.vue. In this case I store the data in each file, and inside products have each one product of 20 products. Everything run good, but while I try to get the data as showing per id in route-link then already in detail page, how to show the data per id in products? This is my products data inside ProductHome and Products:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="product-home">
    <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile">
      <div class="column is-3" v-bind:key="product.id" v-for="product in products.slice(0,8)">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-image">
            <figure class="image is-4by3">
              <img v-bind:src="product.imgSrc" v-bind:alt="product.productName">
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-content">
                <p class="title is-5">{{ product.productName }}</p>
                <p class="subtitle is-6">${{ product.price }}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="media-right">
                <router-link :to="'products/' + product.id" class="button is-small">Detail</router-link>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
              <small>Length: {{ product.length }} CM</small>
              <br>
              <small>Width: {{ product.width }} CM</small>
              <br>
              <small>Size: {{ product.size }} CM</small>
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'product',
  data () {
    return {
      products: [
        {id: 0, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 1', price: '30,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 1, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 2', price: '25,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 2, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 3', price: '35,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 3, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 4', price: '22,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 4, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 5', price: '29,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 5, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 6', price: '24,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 6, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 7', price: '32,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 7, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 8', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 8, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 9', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 9, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 10', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 10, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 11', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 11, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 12', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 12, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 13', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 13, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 14', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 14, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 15', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 15, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 16', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 16, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 17', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 17, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 18', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 18, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 19', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 19, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 20', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'}
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

ProductDetail.vue:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="product-detail container">
    {{ product.productName }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ProductDetail',
  data () {
    return {
      products: [
        {id: 0, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 1', price: '30,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 1, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 2', price: '25,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 2, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 3', price: '35,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 3, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 4', price: '22,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 4, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 5', price: '29,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 5, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 6', price: '24,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 6, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 7', price: '32,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 7, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 8', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 8, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 9', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 9, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 10', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 10, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 11', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 11, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 12', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 12, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 13', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 13, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 14', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 14, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 15', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 15, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 16', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 16, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 17', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 17, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 18', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 18, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 19', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'},
        {id: 19, imgSrc: 'https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png', productName: 'Clothes 20', price: '40,0', length: '99', width: '99', size: '99'}
      ]
    }
  },
  props: ['products']
}
</script>
```

And in my routing index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/pages/home/Home'
import Products from '@/components/pages/product/Products'
// import ProductDetail from '@/components/pages/product/ProductDetail'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/products',
      name: 'Products',
      component: Products
    },
    {
      path: '/products/:id',
      component: { Products }
    }
  ]
})
```

**Update**

Comment: This is close to incomprehensible - e.g. what does "because I store it manually related page I want to call the data" mean? Do you use Google Translate (directly or indirectly)?

Comment: Sorry my English not too good. I mean the data I put on each Files in ProductDetail.vue, Products.vue, and ProductHome.vue, how could I get the data in `products: [ {data_array}, {etc} ]` can be called without put that one by one inside ProductDetail.vue, Products.vue, and ProductHome.vue? And how to show data by each id `products: [ {data_array}, {etc} ]` inside ProductDetail.vue? Like dynamic posts if u are using laravel there is show detail post, something like that bro I mean :) hehe, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the proper product in the detail view, use a computed property to find the entry in the products array:

```
export default {
  ...
  computed: {
    product() {
      let product = this.products.find(product => product.id === this.$route.params.id);
      return product;
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

To get the detail link to work, give a `name` to your `/products/:id` route, e.g. `detail` and use it with `v-bind` in `router-link`:

In the code:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    ...
    {
      path: '/products/:id',
      name: 'detail',
      component: { Products }
    }
  ]
})
```

In the template:

```
<router-link v-bind:to="{ name: 'detail', params: { id: product.id } }" class="button is-small">Detail</router-link>
```

Comment: The detail link is working, while in show detail the product how to collect the data per id I mean?